# PRMO 2018 question

Tags: number-theory

Consider all 6-digit numbers of the form abccba
where b is odd. Determine the number of all such
6-digit numbers that are divisible by 7.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

The number $abccba$ is $100001a + 10010b + 1100c$. We can fairly quickly determine that
$$100001 \equiv -1 \mod 7$$
$$10010 \equiv 0 \mod 7$$
$$1100 \equiv 1 \mod 7$$

Can you take it from here?